# Update file on git add with clean filter and sed

Tags: windows, git, sed, mingw, gitattributes

I have a small header at the top of some of my project files that I want to make sure are updated with the current year every time I make a change to them. I'm having an issue with my clean filter in git throwing an error:

First, I have a file called `testClass.cs` on my master branch:

```
// *********************
// File active 2011-2014
// *********************
```

I then make a small change to the file:

```
// *********************
// File active 2011-2014
// *********************

// First commit, wahoo!
```

then I run `git add testClass.cs` to stage the change for the next commit. This runs my git clean filter that uses `sed` to attempt to edit the file inplace to update the year in the header to 2015 (ie, 2011-2014 should be changed to 2011-2015). Here is the config, with the filter setting:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly

[filter "updatedate"]
    clean = sed -i "s/2011-[[:digit:]]\\{4\\}/2011-$(date '+%Y')/" %f
```

The issue that I am having, is that the add/update fails due to a "Device or resource busy" error. Seemingly to have something to do with the temp file that sed creates. The sed command works fine if I test it on the command line, but fails when used as a filter.

```
$ git add testClass.cs
sed: cannot rename ./sed0jmaI2: Device or resource busy
error: external filter sed -i s/2011-[[:digit:]]\{4\}/2011-$(date '+%Y')/ %f failed 4
error: external filter sed -i s/2011-[[:digit:]]\{4\}/2011-$(date '+%Y')/ %f failed
```

I'm using git bash version 2.5.3 (MINGW64).

Comment: Are you sure the filename that sed sees exists where it is supposed to? The filters appear to expect the file contents on standard input and are expected to write to standard output. Perhaps try dropping `-i` and `%f`? (Also you probably want to make sure you don't modify anything farther into the file than a few lines.)

Comment: @EtanReisner, dropping the `-i` flag seems to be more what I want (the error goes away, anyway). The issue I see now, is that the date is updated as part of the git history (I can see it added to the diff), but the file itself is not modified.

Comment: That's not what filters do. They explicitly change the data between the worktree and the repository. On purpose. That's what they are for.

Comment: Using filters for this seems like a misuse to me. I would sooner suggest a pre-commit (or similar) hook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few things going on strange here, one is that you are not using `sed` like a stream. `clean` takes standard input runs it through the command and modifies the file as standard output. its more like `cat foo.txt | sed 's/foo/bar/'`. So there is no need for `-i` and it will break things. Other than that I think the regex isn't liked by git, you can do better in this case by being more specific.

```
[filter "updatedate"]
    clean = sed "s/2011-20[01][0-9]/2011-$(date '+%Y')/"
```

Note that this won't change your local copy, you will have to pull to see the changes in the pulled directory, thus the `smudge` command.